# Simple JQuery animate(); not working in ie 8?

Tags: jquery, html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

I have been working on this snippet of jquery that works fine in chrome and firefox, ie 10, and ie 9, but ie 8 will not work. Where am I going wrong, the jquery written seems to be correct. What can I do to enhance this code and get it working on ie 8. Check out the search bar in the top right corner on chrome or firefox (it has working functionality). Then check it in ie 8. It seems as though the code is being terminated or not finishing the function? Visit harley.bushcommunications.com.

```
 /* SEARCH DROP DOWN */

$('#header .search').mouseenter( function() {
    $('.search').css({'z-index': '2', 'filter': 'progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#d8ffffff, endColorstr=#d8ffffff)', '-ms-filter': '"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#d8ffffff, endColorstr=#d8ffffff)"'});
    $('#header .search').animate({width: '15%'});
    $('#header .search > ul').show();
    $('#header input.input-hide, .search-submit').css({'display': 'block'});
    $('.cal').css({'z-index': '1'});
    $('.cal .right-text').fadeOut();
});

$('#header .search').mouseleave(function() {
    $('#header > .serach > ul > p').css({'opacity': '0.0'}, 0);
    $('.cal').css({'z-index': '2'});
    $('.search').css({'z-index': '1'});   
    $('#header .search > ul').hide(0);
    $('#header .search').animate({width: "125"}, 250);
    $('input.input-hide,  .search-submit').hide();
    $('.cal .right-text').fadeIn();
});

/* CALENDAR DROP DOWN */

$('#header .cal').hover(function() {
    $(this).animate({width: '15%'}, 250, 'linear');
    $(this).find('ul').animate({'height': '200'},1000, 'easeOutBounce');
    $('.calendar').show();
},
function() {
    $('#header .cal').animate({width: '125'}, 500);
    $('#header .cal > ul').animate({height: '0'}, 250, 'linear');
    $('.calendar').hide();              
});
```

Answer (score 2):

IE8 does not support `opacity`. It instead uses `filter:alpha(opacity=X)` where X is a value from 0 to 100.